# How to retun max occurence of value inside mongoDB array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array in mongodb: I want to max occured `devDependenciesList` value from given array

```
[{
    "_id" : 0,
    "repoId" : 460078,
    "devDependenciesList" : [ 
        "value1", 
        "value2", 
        "value3", 
        "value4"
    ]
},{
    "_id" : 1,
    "repoId" : 1232,
    "devDependenciesList" : [ 
        "value1", 
        "value4", 
        "value7", 
        "value93"
    ]
},{
    "_id" : 2,
    "repoId" : 5423,
    "devDependenciesList" : [ 
        "value1", 
        "value23", 
        "value3", 
        "value4"
    ]
}]
```

The output should be :

```
[value1:3,value4:3,value3:2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array content and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on each value as the grouping key with a [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Which would return:

```
{ "_id" : "value23", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "value93", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "value7", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "value2", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "value3", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "value1", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "value4", "count" : 3 }
```

That's the basic data right there, but if you really want the "key/count" form you can do:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "items": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$items" }
  }}
])
```

Which would return:

```
{
        "value1" : 3,
        "value4" : 3,
        "value3" : 2,
        "value23" : 1,
        "value93" : 1,
        "value7" : 1,
        "value2" : 1
}
```

The additional [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) are to collect all the results into a single document with an array named with `"k"` and `"v"` elements. You want this form for the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator which is used in the next [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage returning the final output.

You need a MongoDB version which supports those latter operators, but really you don't. This is actually most efficiently done in client code. Such as with JavaScript in the shell:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }    
]).toArray().reduce((o,e) => Object.assign(o, { [e._id]: e.count }),{})
```

And that produces the same results as above.

And of course if you wanted to exclude all of the singular results or something similar, just add a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) after the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }    
]).toArray().reduce((o,e) => Object.assign(o, { [e._id]: e.count }),{})
```

Or using the node native driver that would be something like:

```
let result = (await db.collection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }    
]).toArray()).reduce((o,{ _id, count }) => ({ ...o,  [_id]: count }),{})
```

Given usage of `async/await` on the return of an actual array and the use of ES6 features like Object spread and destructuring.

Which of course is just:

```
{ "value1" : 3, "value4" : 3, "value3" : 2 }
```

---

Just for reference, here's a fully reproducible listing:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

const data = [
  {
    "_id" : 0,
    "repoId" : 460078,
    "devDependenciesList" : [
      "value1",
      "value2",
      "value3",
      "value4"
    ]
  },{
    "_id" : 1,
    "repoId" : 1232,
    "devDependenciesList" : [
      "value1",
      "value4",
      "value7",
      "value93"
    ]
  },{
    "_id" : 2,
    "repoId" : 5423,
    "devDependenciesList" : [
      "value1",
      "value23",
      "value3",
      "value4"
    ]
  }
];

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  let client;

  try {
    client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, opts);

    const db = client.db('test');

    // Clean data
    await db.collection('collection').deleteMany();

    // Insert data
    await db.collection('collection').insertMany(data);

    let result = (await db.collection('collection').aggregate([
      { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
      { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }
    ]).toArray()).reduce((o, { _id, count }) => ({ ...o, [_id]: count }),{});

    log(result);

    let sample = await db.collection('collection').aggregate([
      { "$unwind": "$devDependenciesList" },
      { "$sortByCount": "$devDependenciesList" },
    ],{ "explain": true }).toArray();

    log(sample);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    if (client)
      client.close();
  }

})()
```

And output showing the expected result and the "explain" output to show that `$sortByCount` is not a "real" aggregation stage and is just a shorter way of typing things that existed way back with MongoDB 2.2:

```
{
  "value1": 3,
  "value4": 3,
  "value3": 2
}
[
  {
    "stages": [
      {
        "$cursor": {
          "query": {},
          "fields": {
            "devDependenciesList": 1,
            "_id": 0
          },
          "queryPlanner": {
            "plannerVersion": 1,
            "namespace": "test.collection",
            "indexFilterSet": false,
            "parsedQuery": {},
            "winningPlan": {
              "stage": "COLLSCAN",
              "direction": "forward"
            },
            "rejectedPlans": []
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": {
          "path": "$devDependenciesList"
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$devDependenciesList",
          "count": {
            "$sum": {
              "$const": 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "sortKey": {
            "count": -1
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "ok": 1,
    "operationTime": "6674186995377373190",
    "$clusterTime": {
      "clusterTime": "6674186995377373190",
      "signature": {
        "hash": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
        "keyId": 0
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: How to use  it with node js?? Mean how to get its callback value??

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal There's an example above. All the native driver methods either return a Promise or you can use a callback. But otherwise everything is identical.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal Sorry. Just "freetyping" into here without checking syntax. Fixed the statement now.

Comment: If you want to reduce the aggregate query you can use $sortByCount instead, see the query in solution below. It will serve the same purpose.

Comment: @VikashSingh All that does is it "expands" into the `$group` and `$sort` stages as shown here. It's really just a "helper" and you can see the actual expansion using the `"explain"` option with aggregate. Also since it was introduced in MongoDB 3.4 it defeats the basic point of what I was saying, in that you can do this right back to MongoDB 2.2 without needing "special operators".

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `$sortByCount` and `$unwind` like as below :

```js
db.getCollection("test").aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$devDependenciesList"
    },
    {
        $sortByCount: "$devDependenciesList"
    }
]).map((obj)=>{return {[obj._id]:obj.count}})
```

This is the simple and short solution i could think of.